# Flutter `protoc` does not generate built-in types

Tags: flutter, protocol-buffers, protoc

`/proto/ping.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
service SvcPing {
  rpc Ping (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (Pong);
}

message Pong {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Running the command `protoc proto/ping.proto --dart_out=grpc:lib/grpc` generates the necessary code but without the `"google/protobuf/empty.proto"`:
[image]

```
$ which protoc
/usr/bin/protoc
```

Comment: You may need to include `empty.proto` in your `protoc` command. Many languages include pre-generated (packages|modules) for the Google Well-known Types but perhaps Dart does not.

Comment: More details please

Comment: Protobufs and all dependencies must be compiled. In the case of Google's Well-known Types (WKT), the protobuf sources are shipped with `protoc` (generally) and, for many languages, compiled versions of WKT are provided too. It appears that these aren't provided with Dart (though you should Google for a Dart package for Well-known Types). If that's the case then you should compile `empty.proto` yourself and reference the generated stubs as appropriate. Do you have a copy of `empty.proto`?

Comment: Look in your `protoc` folder alongside `bin` you may have `include` (this will become a `--proto_path=/path/to/include`) and this should include `google/protobuf/empty.proto` which you can reference `protoc --proto_path=/path/to/include --dart_out={somewhere} /path/to/include/google/protobuf/empty.proto`

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 23.10. `/usr/bin/protoc` and `/usr/include` does not have anything related to proto at all

Comment: I am not a Dart developer. One way to get the WKTs is to install `protoc` directly (see [Releases](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases)). In that folder there is an `include` folder containing `empty.proto`. You could then `protoc --proto_path=/path/to/include --dart_out=grpc:{somewhere} path/to/include/google/protobuf/empty.proto`. It's possible (but unclear) whether the Dart [`grpc`](https://pub.dev/packages/grpc) includes [`empty.pb.dart`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/blob/master/example/googleapis/lib/src/generated/google/protobuf/empty.pb.dart).